# Calling a class file and its methods

Tags: java, class, methods, instantiation

Here is my current code In the SalesManager client application i want to  prompt the user for the filename. Then nstantiate a SalesAnalyzer object and call all the methods above, outputting the results from each method.

How do I call  SalesAnaylzer and all of its methods?

SalesManager:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;;

public class SalesManager
{
    public static void main( String []args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println(" What is the name of the file");
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName= scan.next();
    }
}
```

and here is the class file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SalesAnaylzer {

    DecimalFormat pricePattern = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");
    int[][] sales = new int[3][4];

    public SalesAnaylzer(String fileName) throws IOException {

        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                sales[row][col] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String data = "";
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            data = data + "\nStore " + (row + 1) + ": ";
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                data = data + "QTR " + (col + 1) + ": " + pricePattern.format(sales[row][col]) + " ";
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public double totalSales() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                total = total + sales[row][col];
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public double highStoreSales(int store) {
        double highest = 0.0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            if (sales[row][store] > highest)
                highest = sales[row][store];
        }
        return highest;
    }

    public double averageStoreSales(int quarter) {
        double total = 0.0;
        double avg = 0.0;
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
            total = total + sales[quarter][col];
        }
        avg = (total / 4);
        return avg;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create a Scanner and call its methods? It seems you managed to do that. Why do you think it would be different to construct a SalesAnalyzer and call its methods?

Comment: Do you mean reflectively? Or are you asking a newbie Java question here? Try https://www.google.com/search?q=call+method+reflection+java

Comment: "and call all the methods above" - what methods above?

Comment: thats what i'm getting confused on I guess i'm just over thinking it, Im not figuring out how to call the methods?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure they are in the same package so that you can directly call on the constructor and methods of the `SalesAnaylzer` class. Then just create a SalesAnalyzer object like you would any other:

```
SalesAnaylzer sA = new SalesAnaylzer(filename);
System.out.println(sA);
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, lets imagine you saved both classes in the package (folder) named "myPackage". First thing you should add in every class is this line of code:

```
package myPackage;
```

After you did that you have to create a new instance of `SalesAnalyzer` inside the `SalesManager` class, the same way you created a new `Scanner`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Here you created a new Scanner
```

Create a new `SalesAnalyzer`:

```
SalesAnalyzer newSA = new SalesAnalyzer();
```

Now, if you want to access any method, you have to write the name of yours `SalesAnalyzer` object, dot after that and then name of the method you wish to call.

```
/*
* Here you created a new String named fileName and added it value that
* yours "next" method returned. "next" is a method inside Scanner object
* and you called for it by writing "scan.next()".
*/

String fileName = scan.next();
```

This is what next method looks like inside Scanner object:

```
public String next() {
    ensureOpen();
    clearCaches();

    while (true) {
        String token = getCompleteTokenInBuffer(null);
        if (token != null) {
            matchValid = true;
            skipped = false;
            return token;
        }
        if (needInput)
            readInput();
        else
            throwFor();
    }
}
```

Now, lets say you want to call for `totalSales` method inside your `SalesAnalyzer`. It's a method that returns double type value. In case you want to save that value to some variable in your `SalesManager` class you have to create variable of double type and call for the `totalSales` method after. It should look like this:

```
double totalS = newSA.totalSales();
```

This way you accessed to method `totalSales` inside your `SalesAnalyzer` from your `SalesManager` class and saved the value it returned to double variable named `totalS`. Hopefully I clarified anything to you and helped you even a little. If you have any further question feel free to ask.